# Java multiplication error

Tags: java

Need help for the question.

Cant seem to figure out why Subsidized Premium is printed out as 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class qns1b
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter the age next birthday of the citizen: ");
        int age = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the annual value of residence: $ ");
        double annualValue = kb.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter number of properties: ");
        int noOfProperties = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the monthly income: $ ");
        double monthlyIncome = kb.nextDouble();

        double subsidy = 0;

        double annualPremiumBfoSubsidy = 0;
        double annualPremium;
        double subsidisedPremium = 0;
        double subsidisedDeduction = 0;


        subsidisedDeduction = annualPremiumBfoSubsidy*subsidy; 
        subsidisedPremium =   annualPremiumBfoSubsidy-subsidisedDeduction;

        //(ii)

        if (age <= 20 && monthlyIncome <= 1100 && noOfProperties == 1)

        {
            subsidy = 0.25;
            annualPremium = 50;
            annualPremiumBfoSubsidy = 130;
            System.out.println("Previous Premium: $" +annualPremium+ " " + "Current Premium: $" +annualPremiumBfoSubsidy);
            System.out.println("Subsidised Premium: $" +subsidisedPremium+ " " +"(deduct $" +subsidisedDeduction+ "for 30% of" +annualPremiumBfoSubsidy+ ")");

        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.print ("good");
        }

}
}
```

Comment: double annualPremiumBfoSubsidy = 0;
        double annualPremium;
        double subsidisedPremium = 0;
        double subsidisedDeduction = 0; change these values  update these in any of loop and do difference

Comment: Your problem is one of magical thinking. If you have `A = B - C` and later you change B or C, A is not going to magically change. If you want A to reflect B or C's change, then you have to re-calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

It is the difference of two variables set to zero.

```
 subsidisedPremium =   annualPremiumBfoSubsidy-subsidisedDeduction;
```

Both these variables were set to zero before.

Comment: if i dont initialized it to 0, i will get error that its not initialized

Comment: True. You have to set them to the value they should get. Otherwise it does not make sense to calculate the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your subsidised premium=

```
subsidisedPremium =   annualPremiumBfoSubsidy-subsidisedDeduction;
```

And, your:

```
double annualPremiumBfoSubsidy = 0;
```

and

```
double subsidisedDeduction = 0;
```

Here:

```
subsidisedDeduction = annualPremiumBfoSubsidy*subsidy; 
subsidisedPremium =   annualPremiumBfoSubsidy-subsidisedDeduction;
```

Your `subsidy` is 0 and `annualPremiumBfoSubsidy` is 0, so `subsidisedDeduction` remains 0.

Also, Both `annualPremiumBfoSubsidy` and `subsidisedDeduction` are 0.

So, 0*0 = 0, and 0-0 = 0. Isn't it?